# How to install WiFi and bluetooth driver on Linux?

Tags: linux, wifi, bluetooth, manjaro

I recently bought a new HP laptop. WiFi and Bluetooth work out of the box in Windows 10, but not in Manjaro Linux 17. I am running Kernel 4.14 LTS.

To check which network controller is installed, I used the following command

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```

Output:

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter [10ec:d723]
        DeviceName: WLAN
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]

Comment: Please specify which Network Controller model you are using?

Comment: If you don't know the network controller, then state the exact make (HP) and model of the laptop.

Comment: Could you give the return of "lspci"  command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest updating your Kernel using Manjaro Settings manager.

Realtek RTL8723DE module for Linux kernel version >= 4.15

Install:

```
git clone https://github.com/dhatwalia/rtl8723de.git -b 4.15-up
dkms add ./rtl8723de
dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
depmod -a
reboot
```

Uninstall:

```
rmmod -f 8723de
dkms uninstall rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
dkms remove rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 --all
depmod -a
reboot
```